# Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails Correctly

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

## PROBLEM

I know there is already a question in regards to this but I think that the issue that causes might be different based on what they are saying. I have the following setup:

1. **grails version:** 2.3.4
2. **Hibernate plugin:** runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6"
3. My Bootstrap is empty
4. My Controller and Service tests are commented

This grails application has multiple data sources (I am not sure if this fact has anything to do with it) and it occurs after a call against a Domain object from the second datasource which has been reversed engineered with the grails reverse engineer plugin (have done that on a separate project and then imported to my project.

This is the GORM call that causes the problem from both the **Controller** and the **Service** layers

```
def campusAttributes = CampusAttribute.findAllByNameLike("%Next Option%")
```

I have found some other complains about this and it seems to be an issue with Maven and the grails hibernate plugin version but in that scenario the issue was very particular to grails 2.3.1 and a specific hibernate plugin version.

All I did was a **grails run-app** (did not build the app with maven neither have any mocking)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem upgrading a grails project from 2.2.4 to 2.3.6. I've upgraded the hibernate plugin from 3.6.10 to 3.6.10.8 and the error was gone.

Comment: I'm facing the problem with 3.6.10.18 hibernate version. My grails version is 2.3.8

Comment: This error will also pop if you use a reserved word in mysql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 3):

I add the same error after upgrading from grails 2.3.0 to 2.3.5. 
What solved it in my case was to modify plugin dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy, for hibernate and tomcat to set to required level for 2.3.5 :
* new tomcat : build ':tomcat:7.0.50' (old :build ":tomcat:7.0.42). 
* new Hibernate : runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.7' (old : runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.1").

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I had moved a Domain class's package For example it was originally

com.a.DomainClass
but I moved it to
com.b.DomainClass

And I had not cleaned the project